# iOS - App crashes in Release but not in Debug mode. [__NFCString count]: unrecognized selector sent to instance xxx

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a category of `NSObject` in which I have swizzled the `valueForKeyPath:` method. If the keyPath contains `[]`, then it assumes that the object is an `array` and calls the `objectAtIndex:` method for the given index.

```
+ (void)load {
    Method original, swizzled;

    original = class_getInstanceMethod(self, @selector(valueForKeyPath:));
    swizzled = class_getInstanceMethod(self, @selector(valueForExtendedKeyPath:));
    method_exchangeImplementations(original, swizzled);
}
```

Implementation:

```
- (id)valueForExtendedKeyPath:(NSString * __autoreleasing *)keyPath {
token = keyPath; 
container = self;
if([token hasPrefix:@"["]) {
    NSExpression *expression;
    NSInteger index, count;

    count = [container count];
    token = [token substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(1, token.length - 2)];
    token = [token stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"@lastIndex" withString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)count - 1]];

    expression = [NSExpression expressionWithFormat:token];
    index = [[expression expressionValueWithObject:nil context:nil] integerValue];
    if(index >= 0 && index < count) {
        value = container[index];
    }
}
```

}

I have made sure that container is always an `NSArray`. In `debug mode`, the app runs fine but in `Release mode`, the app crashes with the following error:

```
[__NFCString count]: unrecognized selector sent to instance xxx
```

Comment: show more code its missing `container` part

Comment: Just wondering, in your `valueForExtendedKeyPath` where is `token` defined? Shouldn't that be `keyPath` ?

Comment: problem with [container count],Pls check container is string

Comment: The problem is that container is of type String in Release mode. Itr should be an array.

Comment: Its an array in Debug mode.

Comment: Can you place the declaration of container..!Container is declared as NSArray or anything else..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to avoid from override functions in `Category` (in your case `valueForKeyPath`), It will lead to BAD stuff.

In your code above, I don't see that u casting something here: `container = self;` (3rd line)

Try to debug step by step :
In release mode u can't really debug, but you can do some introspection like this:

```
NSLog(@"isString:%i", [self isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]);
```

Answer (score 1):

As of now you can avoid crash using below code..(Checking condition of container type)

```
- (id)valueForExtendedKeyPath:(NSString * __autoreleasing *)keyPath 
{
    token = keyPath; 
    container = self;
    if([token hasPrefix:@"["]) 
    {
        NSExpression *expression;
        NSInteger index, count;

            if(container isKindOfClass:[NSArray class])
            {
            count = [container count];
            token = [token substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(1, token.length - 2)];
            token = [token stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"@lastIndex" withString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)count - 1]];

            expression = [NSExpression expressionWithFormat:token];
            index = [[expression expressionValueWithObject:nil context:nil] integerValue];
            if(index >= 0 && index < count) 
            {
                value = container[index];
            }
            }
          else
           {
               NSLog(@"The container is string");
           }
        }
    }
```

Hope it helps you...